# Running code once when starting sveltekit app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, svelte, sveltekit

I'm currently writing a sveltekit app, which needs to connect to a postgresql database to handle logins, etc. The package I'm using right now is `pg` on npm, which I'd like to use to create a pool of clients that my app can use whenever a user makes a request (I know how to do this part).

The only issue is that I can't find the place in sveltekit where I can put the code to initialize the client pool, and since it needs to run only once, I can't put it in my endpoint files or in `+hooks.js`. My end goal is to be able to access the pool of clients in all of my endpoint files, which should already be initialized and set up.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73143779/reuse-firebase-object-instance-in-multiple-components/73148693#73148693

Comment: Solved. Please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418568/how-to-execute-code-on-sveltekit-app-start-up/76505892#76505892